# Struggling to create clientless IM with Lync

Tags: html, lync

I need to make a clientless IM system with Lync and am struggling to find any existing information on this to help me.

Is this possible? and could anyone help/point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've included HTML5 as a tag, so I'm going to assume you want to create an web-page that has IM functionality built in.

UCWA is exactly what you need in this instance. UCWA is a rest-like API for accessing Lync for IM and Presence. You can use UCWA with anything that does HTTP request/response, but all the examples are using Javascript. Have a look at [UCWA.Lync.com](http://ucwa.lync.com/) - where you will find online examples and code samples.

Also, if you're developing a project on this, depending on your timeline, you should also be aware of a new technology recently announced at the Lync Conference 2014. Its code name is JLync, and it will bring "browser extensibility with voice, video & content."

Comment: Tom, not sure if you will see this but i'll ask anyway. I am struggling to grasp how exactly this works, do i install Lync server and then use send it messages from my own front end contact style thing, and then send them from the server to another computer with my own front end contact style thing? Sorry if that doesnt make sense, just finding it hard to grasp this whole concept.

Comment: UCWA is a way of making connections to Lync via the medium of HTTP. You'll need a fully set up Lync 2013 environment CU1+. Once you have all that you can use UCWA from any machine; you don't need anything special on the client machine (that's the point). The messages you send are HTTP GETs and POSTs and are sent to the FE (the exact URL is given to you as part of the authentication process). Lync then internalises signing in/sending IMs etc: you only deal with the URL via HTTP. Hope that helps!Have a look at the UCWA posts Shelby has done: http://blogs.claritycon.com/ucpractice/author/shagman/

Comment: Thanks so much Tom, I know information is hardly sparse on the subject but I was finding it so hard just to get an explanation on how it works pseudo style.